# Hadoop1.0.4 Example not running

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I recently installed Hadoop 1.0.4 with cygwin on windows 7 (64bit).
I have configured *-site.xml according to [this site](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/single_node_setup.html). I am able to do everything perfectly but my program hangs at this particular point:

```
$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-*.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
13/02/12 15:15:17 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for         
your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
13/02/12 15:15:17 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
13/02/12 15:15:17 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 16
13/02/12 15:15:17 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201302121513_0002
13/02/12 15:15:18 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
```

I have checked jobtracker and tasktracker also. One node is live and total submission is 1 but there is no active jobs!
There is nothing running there.. no mapping/no reducing!
I am so much confused right now, I am not able to do anything else. Please help wat to do next.
P.S: I am trying pseudo-single node setup only on one machine.
please guide me what to do?
even jps command is also not working?
I have set the path to C:\jdk_1.6.0_15.

Comment: jps is not working on windows-cygwin environment,try with "ps" command.which will gives number of java process running & other also

Comment: ok.. and wat abt my main problem?

Answer (score 0):

For JPS to work give the path as  `C:\jdk_1.6.0_15/bin`

And about the Job not running, check the Job-tracker logs. 
It might be that some configuration error is resulting in the aborting of the job.

You can also specifically try to set the maximum Number of mappers and reducers in the configuration. It might be set to zero

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

1)Check your hadoop condition using jps/ps, Are all components are working fine ?

2) check java version.it must be either be sun/oracle jdk > = 6, check java configuration(mainly JAVA_HOME) in hadoop-env.sh

3) check `/hadoop-1.*/lib/native` folder for native libraries, Does these supports for your platform?

If they are not there,then compile using this instruction [link](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/native_libraries.html), because (native library are only tested with *nix platform i.e. Unix/Linux systems,  & then load libraries into your filesystem as mentioned

useful other [links](http://www.quora.com/How-can-I-get-proper-native-libraries-for-Hadoop-0-21-0-to-be-able-to-mount-HDFS-using-fuse-dfs)

even if this is not working,then try with hadoop-0.20,because thats working with windows-64 bit
for example you can try

`hadoop-0.20.2/bin/hadoop jar /home/trendwise/apache/hadoop-0.20.2/hadoop-0.20.2-examples.jar pi 16 1000`

Comment: hey thanks for your answer.. 
mine is windows 7 64-bit.
when i checked /hadoop-1.*/lib/native, I found these two libraries:
    1. Linux-amd64-64
    2. Linux-i386-32
I dnt kno whether these are compatible or not.
please tell wat shud I do?

Comment: @Hemant ,why not to try building native libraries instead of using/trying with uncompatible one ?, just try. If you are in Hurry,then simply install VirtualBox/VMWarePlayer,make virtual OS & try over there the "Hadoop" thing